# Batchnorm layer present after freeze for inference from DeeplabV3+ model, is this ok?

Tags: tensorflow, semantic-segmentation, tensorflow-model-garden

After export of a trained model the BatchNorm layers are still present. I have read somewhere these should be removed for inference for two reasons:

1. Network output might be wrong
2. Speedup of the whole [network](https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-up-inference-with-batch-normalization-folding-8a45a83a89d8#:%7E:text=It%20means%20that%20during%20inference,into%20a%20single%20linear%20transformation!)

Well, I am in doubt of 1. but the second fact sounds logical, so my question is:
How to filter out the layers then?

Environment: models from Tensorflow GitHub and trained on Tensorflow 1.15.3.

Export of used:

```
python deeplab/export_model.py \
--num_classes=2 --model_variant="mobilenet_v3_large_seg" \
--dataset="123" \
--checkpoint_path=training \
--crop_size=384 \
--crop_size=384 \
--export_path=graph.pb
```

Excerpt Network graph:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/MobilenetV3/input:0' shape=(1, 768, 768, 3) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/weights:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 16) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/weights/read:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 16) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/Conv2D:0' shape=(1, 384, 384, 16) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/gamma:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/gamma/read:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/beta:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/beta/read:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/moving_mean/read:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/moving_variance/read:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNormV3:0' shape=(1, 384, 384, 16) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNormV3:1' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNormV3:2' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNormV3:3' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNormV3:4' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNormV3:5' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>)
(<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV3/Conv/hard_swish/add/y:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are true. Batchnormalization is only meant to be used during the training just like Dropout. You actually do not need to handle it yourself.

During inference, just use model.predict and the library will handle it. Namely, all the batch normalization and dropout layers will be deactivated.

If you need to do more fancy stuff than just predicting, you can also pass the argument Training=False. Check the documentation. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I am doing inference in Tensorflow Java binding, so will check if prediction is doing this also implicit there.

Comment: You are welcome! I do not have any knowledge of Java binding but I would be very surprised if it is not doing the same. Good luck!